# Digital switch for 2000V capacitor

Tags: switches, high-voltage, high-current

I want to produce a discharge of a capacitor against a test cell, as part of a study on high energy states of materials.
I'm using a standard microwave oven transformer as the power supply that I convert to DC with a 4 diode briege. 
The capacitor that I use is from the same microwave oven.
Spec: CH85
1*10-6 F+-3% , 2100V
I'm looking for an electronic switch that will allow me to fully discharge a matching capacitor to the test cell with minimal losses of potential. [image: capacitor spec]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider using a xenon tube like [this one](http://www.sugawara-labs.co.jp/en/xenonflashes/xenon/xenon_flashlamps_with_extremely_short_flash_duration_of_180_ns): -

[image]

It can discharge a capacitor in sub 1 us and can take a capacitor voltage as high as 5 kV. Here is a basic idea of a circuit that can trigger the device: -

[image]